# Is it possible to do the Singstar 'disc swap' on PS4?

Tags: ps4, singstar

The PS3 Singstar had a functionality that allowed you to swap out your disc for a PS2 disc, allowing you to play those songs on PS3.

Is it possible to do the same on PS4 with either a PS3 or PS2 disc?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, your old Singstar discs can't be used on the PS4. Only content purchased through the PSN store can be transferred.